# Constraint composition in haskell

Tags: haskell, constraint-programming

I was trying to use the `Data.Constraint` package to do some constraint programming but I am hitting a wall. Is there an implementation for `compHasLens` in the following example?

```
import qualified Control.Category   as C
import           Data.Constraint

-- | A very simple lens to handle the infinite type problem.
data a :>:  b =
  Lens'
  { getL :: a -> b,modL :: (b -> b) -> a -> a }

instance C.Category (:>:) where
  a . b = Lens' { getL = getL a . getL b,modL = modL b . modL a  }
  id = Lens' { getL = id,modL = id }

class HasLens a b where
  defLens :: a :>: b

composeHasLens :: Dict (HasLens a b) -> Dict (HasLens b c) -> Dict (HasLens a c)
composeHasLens Dict Dict = error "Is there an implementation for this?"
```

The semantics might be a bit strange:

```
instance HasLens A B
instance HasLens B C
instance HasLens A C

lAB :: Dict (HasLens A B)
lAB = Dict
lBC :: Dict (HasLens B C)
lBC = Dict
-- | The one from the instance
lens :: A :>: C
lens = defLens
-- | The composition.
lens' :: A :>: C
lens' = case composeHasLens lAB lBC  of
  Dict -> defLens
```

But if I understand correctly GHC accepts constraints as arguments it seems like it should possible in principle at least?

Comment: Note that Haskell constraints and the `Data.Constraint` module are not for constraint programming (as in solving CSP problems). Haskell's constraints are much more limited. Perhaps the terminology is confusing.

Comment: How evil are you willing to be;  for the compiler to satisfy`Dict @(HasLens a c)` there must be some instance which unifies it, but you've written no such instance in your post.  in GHC, however, single method dictionaries are coercible with their methods, so `unsafeCoerce (defLens @b @c . defLens @a @b)` can get you an implementation.

Comment: Any solution necessarily looses coherence, which is the property that soluable constraints have a unique solution. Your program might have very strange behaviour without this property.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination I mean I understand how evil this is. What you say sound just the right amount of GHC abuse. Maybe turn that into an answer (with disclaimers etc) so I can accept it?

Comment: Frame challenge: what does `Dict (HasLens a b)` do that `a :>: b` does not? Why bother with it at all?

Comment: You can incorporate it in high level composite constraints on values `type HighLvConstr a b c = (Constr1 a b, Constr2 b c, Constr3 a a a, Constr4 Int a)`. Often it is intuitive to a human which types satisfy the `HighLvConstr` but we don't want the user to care about all the corner cases and features required.